# Error with rosinstall: rosws cannot find lib

Tags: ros, rosws, rosinstall

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I migrated from ros diamondback to ros fuerte.
I wanted to create a workspace with rosws as stated on the wiki, but I get this error:

> ERROR Cannot find rosinstall
> libraries, check your installation.
> One frequent cause is that rosinstall
> 0.5 is still installed in /usr/local/lib. No module named
> rosws_cli

I just dont know how to solve that.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/51232/error-with-rosinstall:-rosws-cannot-find-lib/) by [leoa](https://answers.ros.org/users/3868/leoa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2012-12-30

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [leoa](https://answers.ros.org/users/3868/leoa/) on 2012-12-30**:
Hi @KruseT, I dont know why but I cannot comment on your answer.
I followed your instructions but the problem persists. If I understand right, rosws is looking for: /usr/share/pyshared/rosinstall/rosws_cli.py. Both packages rosinstall and vcstools are up to date.
I also removed what you told me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As the error states, a frequent cause is that you have an old version of rosinstall in /usr/local/lib, as well as a newer version somewhere.

Another source is when you have updated rosinstall, but not vcstools.

So first try to update rosinstall and vcstools:

```
$ sudo apt-get update python-rosinstall python-vcstools
```

If that works, all is well. Else on Ubuntu, you can do

```
$ sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosinstall*
$ sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/vcstools*
$ sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/rosws /usr/local/bin/roslocate /usr/local/bin/rosinstall /usr/local/bin/rosco
```

This might be "python2.6" instead of "python2.7" on some systems.

If you never had them installed via apt-get, do so:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-rosinstall python-vcstools
```

EDIT: Please comment on my question what caused this for you if you find out, it can help us improve the support.

---

Originally posted by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) with karma: 7848 on 2012-12-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am not sure what exactly went wrong in my case, but I had the same issue, and KruseT's advice didn't really work for me.

To resolve the problem (maybe not the cleanest solution), I created a couple of symlinks:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/share/pyshared/rosinstall /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosinstall
sudo ln -s /usr/share/pyshared/vcstools /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/vcstools
```

This worked for me.

---

Originally posted by [sd1074](https://answers.ros.org/users/2110/sd1074/) with karma: 21 on 2013-06-28

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) on 2013-07-31**:
I changed my response to also delete the old executables. Not sure whether that would have helped you.